# Wallop with options not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to implement the Wallop slider: http://pedroduarte.me/wallop/

My ultimate goal is to have a another Wallop slider within another Wallop slider.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to set the `options` for the Wallop slider.

Without options it works as demonstrated here: 
http://pinefallstudios.com/wallop/without_options.html
The code is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Wallop.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop--slide.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>

    <div class="Wallop Wallop--slide">
        <div class="Wallop-list">
            <div class="Wallop-item Wallop-item--current">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop');
        var wallop = new Wallop(wallopEl);


        function onClickNext() {
            wallop.next();
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

However when I try to set `itemClass` and `currentItemClass` to something else it stops working as demonstrated here: http://pinefallstudios.com/wallop/with_options.html
Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Wallop.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop--slide.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>

    <div class="Wallop-outer Wallop--slide">
        <div class="Wallop-list">
            <div class="Wallop-outer-item Wallop-outer-item--current">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-outer-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-outer-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wallopOuterOptions = {
            itemClass: 'Wallop-outer-item',
            currentItemClass: 'Wallop-outer-item--current'
        }
        var wallopEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop-outer');
        var wallop = new Wallop(wallopEl, wallopOuterOptions);


        function onClickNext() {
            wallop.next();
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

I verified that the other options are being set correctly, as you can see in the `console`,  as I'm only setting two options out of several.

What is causing this problem and how can I name my Wallop items so that I can use another inner slider?

**Update**
As explained by @HungCao it's probably due to the CSS rules.

However, how would one create an inner slider in this case?
This doesn't work as demonstrated here: http://pinefallstudios.com/wallop/with_inner.html
Code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Wallop.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wallop--slide.css">
</head>
<body>
</body>

    <!-- Outer Slide -->
    <div class="Wallop-outer Wallop--slide">
        <div class="Wallop-list">
            <div class="Wallop-item Wallop-item--current">
                <img onclick="onClickOuterNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
            <h3>Inner Slider</h3>
            <!-- Inner Slide -->
            <div class="Wallop-inner Wallop--slide">
                <div class="Wallop-list">
                    <div class="Wallop-item Wallop-item-current">
                        <img onclick="onClickInnerNext();" src="http://pedroduarte.me/wallop/141b5b913de38d376ab9c633f344d401.gif" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="Wallop-item">
                        <img onclick="onClickInnerNext();" src="http://pedroduarte.me/wallop/141b5b913de38d376ab9c633f344d401.gif" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
                <img onclick="onClickOuterNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var wallopOuterEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop-outer');
        var wallopOuter = new Wallop(wallopOuterEl);

        var wallopInnerEl = document.querySelector('.Wallop-inner');
        var wallopInner = new Wallop(wallopInnerEl);

        function onClickOuterNext() {
            wallopOuter.next();
        }

        function onClickInnerNext(){
            wallopInner.next();
        }

    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your new classes are overriding some css rules from the original one.
Look at these 2 blocks

Without options:

```
<div class="Wallop Wallop--slide">
        <div class="Wallop-list">
            <div class="Wallop-item Wallop-item--current">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

With options:

```
<div class="Wallop-outer Wallop--slide">
        <div class="Wallop-list">
            <div class="Wallop-outer-item Wallop-outer-item--current">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-outer-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>

            <div class="Wallop-outer-item">
                <img onclick="onClickNext();" src="https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/31752/screenshots/2205163/home.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Do you have any special css rule? Otherwise you should maintain their css rules.

Comment: You're most likely right. However, to create an inner slide how would one go about it? Please see the updated code. Would I need to create two different CSS rules for each slider?

Comment: I still don't really get what you are trying to do here. What is the issue in your updated code?

Comment: Basically I want an outer slider with 3 items. In one of the item I want an inner slider that displays another couple of items.

Comment: I think your html is missing a closing div, it would be great if you can create a fiddler or plunker ...